# Running protractor tests in internet explorer?

Tags: gulp, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to run protractor E2E test in Internet explorer, but failed to make it happen. ( I am succeed with Chrome)

After i run the protractor its opening blank page in IE and it's not opening the URL i specified in the spec.

Comment: can you post the content of  config.js file?

Comment: Thanks for the response . I resolved the issue by installing web-driver for internet explorer

Comment: Make sure it is the 32 bit version. It should default to the 32 bit. We have found that the 64 bit version causes issues when sending keys.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that you mentioned proper syntax in conf file as below,

capabilities: {

'browserName': 'internet explorer',

'platform': 'ANY',

'version': '11'

},

and Ensure that u are opening Valid URL - Website from Spec file, Since it is opening in chrome i hope it is valid one.

Comment: Thanks for the response .
I resolved the issue by installing web-driver for internet explorer

Comment: Great:) then fine